# disable client host connection after many failed attempts in mysql

Tags: mysql

in mysql 5.5 error logs I see many Access denied for user .... from the same ips.  I thought mysql would put a host in blocked_host or something similar after 10 failed connection attempts, but it doesn't seem to be.  Is there a way to enforce this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No that will not be done automatically. You can configure for tracking login failure
event using `auditing logon failure event` and use triggers for performing some 
action on failure event.

See this articles

[auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/)

[Audit logins on MySQL database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/668/audit-logins-on-mysql-database/1434#1434)

But best would be to perform this blocking/locking of account at application level and not at DB level.

[Blocking access to the login page after three unsuccessful login attempts](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/blocking_system_access.php)